# a bug for stack implemented with double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

```
class node{
  int data;

  public:
  node *next;
  node *prev;
  node(int a){data=a; next=NULL; prev=NULL;}
  int retrieve(){return data;}
};

class stack{
  node *top;
  public:
  stack(){top=NULL;}
  void push(node);
  bool empty();
  void printall();
};


void stack::push(node a){
  if(top==NULL)
    top=&a;
  else{
    top->next=&a;
    top->next->prev=top;
    top=&a;
  }
}
```

```
int main(){
  stack st;
  cout<<st.empty()<<endl;
  node k(3);
  node j(4);
  node h(5);
  st.push(k);
  st.push(j);
  st.push(h);
  st.printall();  
}
```

The bug happens at the push function.

When i use gdb to trace the top value just inside the push function, the value of top changes to node a immediately.

I only have one stack instance in the main function and therefore one top, it should keep the same value until i assign new value to it. right?

Can anyone give me some hint?

(Btw, is there a way to add 4 spaces before code instead of typing all of them?)

Comment: The problem is not in the push() function. Actual problem is somewhere else, can you provide main() so, your problem get more clear.

Comment: Is the node you are passing to push() dynamically allocated?

Comment: the main function is included. No, the node is static variable i guess.

Comment: When you do *top=&a;* you are storing the address of the parameter of the function, not the actual variable in main. The parameter will be destroyed after the function exits, leaving a dangling pointer. Pass a pointer to it to avoid that. And allocate your nodes on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: well the question has been answered but i just want to say that stacks shouldn't really have a prev pointer in their nodes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: ya stack should not have. But i just want to print all the data in the stack, it is easier for me to have a prev to backtrace all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack::push(node a)`

```
node x; 
/* other things*/
You wil call this as push(x);
```

You are doing pass by value.Maybe that is causing some issue.

`top=&a;` will  store the address of the formal parameter. It's in the scope of push , when you exit push function the variable will be destroyed.